# Ubuntu resolution problem after updating on virtual box

Tags: updates, virtualbox, resolution

I have just updated my ubuntu to ubuntu trusty and its all zoomed (I guess the resolution). I cant scroll any window to the bottom because it is too big. How do I change this. I have tried going into system settings but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem as well.

In the past this trick worked:

> sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-*

This no longer worked for me with broken virtualbox-guest-x11 dependencies in 14.04.2.  Instead once I installed I did the following:

1. Update to latest VirtualBox version (4.3.12 to 4.3.26)
2. Start the vm
3. Select "Insert Guest Additions CD" from the Devices Menu and ran it
4. Restart

Screen resolution / zoom in virtual box now works properly.  I'm on a mac / osx yosemite.